# Reading lines from data file not returning the correct number of lines?

Tags: c++

I made a conceptual program to add to my larger program, but I'm having an issue with a counter.

I have found plenty of excellent recourses on how to count lines in a data file (using various methods) I've tried all of them.

What is happening is, that I set up 3 arrays to hold various data. Wrote that data to a file.. and now. Before I read the data back I want to be able to know the size ( or how many lines are in the file).

I can print out all of the data from the file but the counter keeps only being set as 1.

In my larger program the number or lines will not be known to begin with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class ReadWrite
{
  public:
    ofstream OutputFile,temp;
    ifstream InputFile;
    string taskID[3]={"1","2","3"};
    string task[3]={"blah1","blah2","blah3"};
    string date[3]={"11/11/1111", "12/12/1212","13/13/1313"};
    string line[3];
    string lines;
    int count=0;
    
    void write2file();
    void readfile();
    void remove();
};
  void ReadWrite::readfile()
  {
    InputFile.open("TODOs.txt");
    if (!InputFile.is_open())
    {
      cout<<"No saved TODOs.\n";
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"TODOs uploading.\n";
      while(InputFile>>lines);
      {
        cout<<lines<<endl;
        count++;
      }
      InputFile.close();
      InputFile.open("TODOs.txt");
      cout<<"lines: "<<count<<endl;
      for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        while(getline(InputFile,line[i]))
        {
          cout<<line[i]<<endl;
        }
      }
      InputFile.close();
    }
  }
  void ReadWrite::write2file()
  {
    OutputFile.open("TODOs.txt");
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
    OutputFile<<taskID[i]<<"\t"<<date[i]<<"\t"<<task[i]<<'\n';
    }
    OutputFile.close();
  }
 

int main()
{
  ReadWrite rw;


  bool progLoop = true;
  do
  {
    // SimpAlphaMenu sam(choices, len);
    // int choice = sam.showMenu();
    char choice; 
    cin>>choice;
    if (choice=='+')
    {
      rw.write2file();
      progLoop=true;
    }
      
    else if (choice=='-')
    {cout<<"You are in -\n";}
    else if (choice=='?')
    {       
      rw.readfile();
      progLoop=true;
    }
    else
      progLoop = false;
  
  }while(progLoop);
}
```

After editing in suggestions from @Retired Ninja the code seems to be working fine.

```
void ReadWrite::readfile()   {
    InputFile.open("TODOs.txt");
    if (!InputFile.is_open())
    {
      cout<<"No saved TODOs.\n";
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"TODOs uploading.\n";

        while(getline(InputFile,lines))  //Edited this line here
        {
          // cout<<lines<<endl;
          count++;
        }
      InputFile.close();
      InputFile.open("TODOs.txt");
      cout<<"lines: "<<count<<endl;
      for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
      {
        while(getline(InputFile,line[i]))
        {
          cout<<line[i]<<endl;
        }
      }
      InputFile.close();
    }   }
```

Comment: If you run this hit "+" to set the data into file first. then "?" should display it all ( with the proper line count-This is where the issue lies.. its not printing the proper line count)

Comment: You have a few problems that I see. `while(InputFile>>lines);` has a semicolon at the end, so the lines in the braces below it are not part of the loop. You should also know that `>>` reads words, not lines. It will stop at the first whitespace it finds. The `while(getline` part has shouldn't be in a loop itself. It will read all of the lines in the file into `line[0]` with each overwriting the last, then fail for the next iterations since the end of the file was reached.

Comment: I did not know that the >> only read words, so thank you for that bit of information. I replaced the while(InputFile>>lines) with while( getline(InputFile,lines)) and now its displaying properly. Can I ask why you say the while(getline... shouldnt be in the loop? Because after changing the first part it seems to be working fine?

Comment: I explained why in my comment. You will read every line of the file into `line[0]` with each overwriting the last in the first iteration of the `for` loop then the rest of the iterations will read nothing because all of the file has already been read. After the loop `line[0]` will contain the last line of the file and the other strings in the array will not be modified.

Comment: I'm sorry! the comment had more too it that wasn't showing, I must have over looked the expand button. But I see it now. My apologize, but thank you for reiterating. I will look into fixing that issue now.